# What are the various types of plist?

Tags: ios, macos, plist

I came to hear from some discussion that there are *binary plist* and *xml plist*.

1. Are there more?
2. What are the different types of Plist?
3. What makes them different from each other?
4. Can I use all for iOS and   OSX development ?

Answer (score 4):

1) No, there are not

2) You already listed the main two.  There is a third (ASCII OpenStep format), but it is deprecated and read-only in all current APIs.

3) Binary format is opaque and smaller, and XML is readable but bigger.

4) Yes, you can

Source: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPropertyListFormat) and [Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html)

Comment: Historically, there’s also the OpenStep/NeXTSTEP property list format, which `NSPropertyListSerialization` can still parse. It is the format used when, for example, printing the description of an array of strings: `()` to indicate an array, array elements are separated by commas, single-word ASCII strings are not quoted, all other strings are quoted.

Comment: Also, CF-Lite, the open source subset of Core Foundation, is able to read and write property lists. Being open source, it is possible to use it in platforms other than iOS and OS X — for example, in Linux Web servers providing services to iOS apps.